# Как узнать длину массива ffi.new('float[?]', n)?

Tags: lua

Имеется массив

```
local tab = ffi.new('float[?]', n);
```

Данный код должен его заполнять (пример):

```
for i=3,tonum,2 do
    tab[#tab+1] = i;
end
```

Однако, возникает ошибка:

```
/usr/bin/lua: ./simplnums.lua:8: type float[21] does not implement the   __len metamethod
    stack traceback:
    [C]: in function '__len'
    ./simplnums.lua:8: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнем с того, что в вашем случаи `tab` не является массивом (кстати говоря в **Lua** нет массивов как таковых, это только частный случай таблиц). Вызов `ffi.new` возвращает некий объект `cdata` - C data object.

Допустим мы хотим, что бы этот объект вёл себя как массив. Для этого в **Lua** есть все возможности, нам надо только задать для него [метатаблицу](http://www.lua.ru/doc/2.8.html) и определить ряд метаметодов. Простейшая реализация будет выглядеть так:

```lua
local ffi = require("ffi")
local CFloatArray = {}

CFloatArray.mt = {
  __len = function (o)
--    print("#o = " .. o.size)
    return o.size
  end,

  __index = function (o, i)
--    print("<= o.data[" .. i .. "]")
    return o.data[i]
  end,

  __newindex = function (o, i, v)
--    print("o.data[" .. i .. "] <= " .. v)
    o.data[i] = v
  end,

  __tostring = function (o)
    local s = "{ "
    local comma = ""
    for i = 0, o.size - 1 do
      s = s .. comma .. o.data[i]
      comma = ", "
    end
    return s .. " }"
  end
}

function CFloatArray.new(size)
  local array = {
    size = size,
    data = ffi.new("float[?]", size)
  }
  setmetatable(array, CFloatArray.mt)
  return array
end
```

Что мы тут имеем? Мы создаем новый объект - таблицу, которая содержит поля `size` (количество элементов массиве) и `data` (это наш сишный массив). Конечно можно было бы работать и так:

```lua
local a = CFloatArray.new(3)
for i = 0, a.size - 1 do a.data[i] = i + 1 end
```

Но мы хотим удобства, и тут на помощь приходят метатаблицы. На необходимо определить следующие метаметоды:

- `__len`: для реализации оператора `#o`
- `__index`: для реализации оператора `<= o[i]`
- `__newindex`: для реализации оператора `o[i] <=`
- `__tostring`: для преобразования в строку (до кучи)

Реализация их довольно проста (в нашем случаи). Это дело можно усложнить, например в индексных операторах `[]` можно добавить проверку на выход индекса за допустимые диапазоны ну т.д. и т.п.

Теперь с нашим объектом мы мажем работать как с обычным массивом (обращаться к элементам по индексу, получать длину, преобразовывать в строку):

```lua
local a = CFloatArray.new(3)
for i = 0, #a - 1 do a[i] = i + 1 end
print("#a = " .. #a .. ", " .. "a = " .. tostring(a))
```

Результат работы:

> `#a = 3, a = { 1, 2, 3 }`

---

## Замечание 1

Все что написано выше хорошо, но есть одно но. **LuaJIT** по умолчанию собран с поддержкой **Lua 5.1**. И если мы выполним `print("#a = " .. #a)`, результат будет такой:

> `#a = 0`

Почему так происходит? Дело в том, что поддержка метаметода `__len` для таблиц реализована только начиная **Lua 5.2**.

Вот как выглядит реализация оператора `#` в [Lua 5.1](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8), т.е. если операнд - таблица, то напрямую возвращается ее размер.

```lua
 function len_event (op)
   if type(op) == "string" then
     return strlen(op)         -- primitive string length
   elseif type(op) == "table" then
     return #op                -- primitive table length
   else
     local h = metatable(op).__len
     if h then
       -- call the handler with the operand
       return (h(op))
     else  -- no handler available: default behavior
       error(···)
     end
   end
 end
```

Вот как выглядит реализация оператора `#` в [Lua 5.2](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.4), т.е. сначала проверяется наличие метаметода `__len`. Если он определен, то происходит вызов. В противном случаи для таблиц возвращается размер напрямую.

```lua
 function len_event (op)
   if type(op) == "string" then
     return strlen(op)      -- primitive string length
   else
     local h = metatable(op).__len
     if h then
       return (h(op))       -- call handler with the operand
     elseif type(op) == "table" then
       return #op              -- primitive table length
     else  -- no handler available: error
       error(···)
     end
   end
 end
```

Решение данной проблемы очень простое, а именно  [пересобрать](http://luajit.org/install.html) **LuaJIT** из исходников с [поддержкой](http://luajit.org/extensions.html) **Lua 5.2** (см. раздел **Extensions from Lua 5.2**). Для этого нам надо:

- Найти файл (в дереве исходников) `src\Makefile`.
- Найти в нем строку `LUAJIT_ENABLE_LUA52COMPAT` и раскомментировать ее.
- Пересобрать. Способ пересборки зависит от целевой и хост платформы. В общем случаи это вызов `make`.

---

## Замечание 2

Теперь по вашему коду. Вызов:

> `tab[#tab+1] = i;`

приведет к ошибке, поскольку си-массивы **не являются** динамическими. Вы создаете массив фиксированной длины и пытаетесь обратиться за его границы.

Если вам нужна большая гибкость при работе с массивами, посмотрите в сторону [lds - LuaJIT Data Structures](https://github.com/neomantra/lds):

> lds provides data structures which hold LuaJIT cdata.
>
> These containers cover the common use cases of Lua tables:
>
> - Array (fixed-size array)
> - Vector (dynamically-sized array)
> - HashMap (key-value store)

---

## Замечание 3

А вообще, всё можно сделать проще. Ведь размер массива вам известен изначально. Почему бы не поступить так:

```lua
local n = 10
local tab = require("ffi").new('float[?]', n)
for i = 0, n - 1 do tab[i] = i end
```

---

## Дополнение <sub>из комментариев</sub>

До сих пор мы рассматривали реализацию интерфейса **FFI** в рамках **LuaJIT**, но существуют библиотеки, которые реализуют этот механизм в рамках "чистого" **Lua**. Например [luaffi](https://github.com/jmckaskill/luaffi) и [luaffifb](https://github.com/facebook/luaffifb). Первая из них достаточно давно заброшена (последний коммит датируется ноябрём 2013 года), а вот вторая библиотека (кстати форк первой) вполне живая.

В дальнейших тестах участвовали **Lua 5.2.4** и **luaffifb**. **luaffi** не участвовала, поскольку лень было собирать. Результаты теста показали, что всё вышеизложенное (механизм метатаблиц) прекрасно работает и без **LuaJIT**.

А вот библиотка **lds - LuaJIT Data Structures** на "чистом" **Lua** не "взлетела". Дальнейшее изучение показало, что в **LuaJIT** и **luaffifb** по разному реализованы некоторые моменты, например функции `ffi.cdef(def)` и `ctype = ffi.typeof(ct)`. Различия там идут на уровне реализации *C declaration parser* (файлы `lj_cparse.c` из LuaJIT и `parser.c` из luaffifb).

**LuaJIT** позволяет создавать шаблонные типы данных, а **luaffifb** такого функционала не имеет. Например в **LuaJIT** мы можем написать следующее;

```lua
-- Declare a struct with a parameterized field type and name:
local ctype = ffi.typeof("uint32_t")  
local name = "id"
ffi.cdef([[
  typedef struct { $ $; } foo_t;
]], ctype, name)

-- Anonymous struct with dynamic names:
local name1 = "a"
local bar_t = ffi.typeof("struct { int $, $; }", name1, "b")

-- Derived pointer type:
local bar_ptr_t = ffi.typeof("$ *", bar_t)

-- Parameterized dimensions work even where a VLA won't work:
local height = 10
local matrix_t = ffi.typeof("uint8_t[$][$]", 20, height)
```

Библиотека **lds - LuaJIT Data Structures** активно использует данный функционал и по этому использовать её с "ходу" совместно с **luaffifb** не получиться.

Comment: Как видите, в моём примере я пишу нечётные числа начиная с трёх.

Comment: А lds с обычной lua идёт? Есть и ffi for lua.

Comment: К сожалению нет. Но если вас смущает использование LuaJIT, то можно посмотреть на эти проекты; https://github.com/jmckaskill/luaffi и https://github.com/facebook/luaffifb . Это реализации FFI интерфейса, совместимые с LuaJIT. Правда сразу оговорюсь, сам я их не пробовал и сказать ни чего не могу. Первый из них похоже заброшен, последний коммит датируется ноябрём 2013, а вот второй - апрель этого года. Там похоже есть поддержка Lua 5.3. И ещё один момент - это хаб Facebook'а.

Comment: Нечётные начиная с 3: `for i = 3, n - 1, 2 do tab[i] = i end` или `for i = 3, #a - 1, 2 do a[i] = i end` если реализовать с использованием метатаблиц.

Comment: Ну, я и говорю, что использую ffi for **lua**, точнее luaffifb.

Comment: Хм, `a[i] = i` не катит, будет `{[3] = 3, [5] = 5}`, а надо {[1] = 3, [2] = 5}

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что `o.data = i` в `__index` вызовет рекурсию.

Comment: @val, тогда так: `for i = 0, #a - 1 do a[i] = (i * 2) + 3 end`

Comment: Рекурсии не будет, поскольку метаметод `__index` связан с таблицей `array = { size = size, data = ffi.new("float[?]", size)  }`, а не с объектом `array.data`. В этом легко убедиться, если раскомментировать `print("<= o.data[" .. i .. "]")`. Сколько будет вызовов оператора `[]`, столько и сообщений выведется в консоль.